# how to specify 2 datakeys values in datalaist and access them in code behind.cs

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, datalist

i have   datakeys  values[ID, Name]
  now i need   to  access the  these value  in  itemupdating   event  of  datalist  control
  can  any one  give the  syntax  for it

thank you

Comment: datakieys  specified in .aspz  page  "ID, Name"
int i1 = dvlist.datakeys[e.keys[0]].tostring();
int i2 = dvlist.datakeys[e.keys[1]].tostring();
 i am   getting    syntax  issue

Comment: here ID -->PK
Name -->FK
  so how  can i get these values  whiling updating  event

Comment: there is no itemupdating event in datalist? I think you are talking about DetailsView.

Comment: is it working for you? or have some issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should be like..

```
   dvlist.DataKey["datakeyName"]
```

OR

```
dvlist.DataKey[keyindex]
```